# How do I change the backlight intensity / brightness of external display ASUS Screenpad

Tags: asus, brightness, backlight, external-monitor

I have the new zenbook 15 which comes with a secondary display in the touchpad. Ubuntu recognizes it just fine, as long as I am using Xorg and intel gpu. The issue however is that the brightness on this is not set to max. As ASUS provides drivers for windows I can adjust the backlight through an app. Not so on linux.

Here is what it looks like on Ubuntu:

[image]

And on Windows:

[image]

This is what `xrandr` shows the display as:

```
HDMI-1 connected 2160x1080+0+1080 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 66mm x 134mm

1080x2160 50.03*+

504x1000 50.03
```

I try to set the brightness via `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 1.5` (ie. above 1) but this only makes the screen more saturated. It seems it does not control the actual backlight.

Any clues? I tried to mess around with ddcutil, using sudo ddcutil detect to get (note i2c-3 is the screenpad):

```
Invalid display
   I2C bus:             /dev/i2c-3
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:           TSB
      Model:            ScreenXpert-
      Serial number:    Unspecified
      Manufacture year: 2011
      EDID version:     1.3
   DDC communication failed

Invalid display
   I2C bus:             /dev/i2c-8
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:           BOE
      Model:            Unspecified
      Serial number:    Unspecified
      Manufacture year: 2018
      EDID version:     1.4
   DDC communication failed
```

I wasn't too sure how to set backlight so I downloaded the GUI for ddccontrol (gddccontrol) and when I tried to change the settings of i2c-3 I see this:

[image]

Comment: Update: Still no solution, but turns out whatever brightness was set on Windows when it last booted will persist on ubuntu. Not ideal but not unworkable.

Answer (score 1):

`asus-wmi` worked great for me until last update. Just found brightness-controller added multiple window support, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

To install, then its 2 toggles, one for each screen when you run the program. Should come up if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fix for asus-wmi](https://github.com/Plippo/asus-wmi-screenpad) kernel module by Plippo (well documented, easy to install). These are the current instructions, but please check in case they have been updated

> #### To install and use this module using dkms:
>
> 1. Please make sure that you are running the kernel that you want to install the module for. So if you did a kernel update, please reboot first so the installation uses the correct kernel version.
> 2. Install DKMS using the method of your distribution. Debian/Ubuntu/etc.:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install dkms
>    ```
>
>    In addition to that, you need to have the headers for your current kernels installed. Most distributions provide a package for that. E.g. Ubuntu:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
>    ```
> 3. Create a directory for the module and download the source code
>
>    ```
>    sudo mkdir /usr/src/asus-wmi-1.0
>    cd /usr/src/asus-wmi-1.0
>    sudo wget 'https://github.com/Plippo/asus-wmi-screenpad/archive/master.zip'
>    sudo unzip master.zip
>    sudo mv asus-wmi-screenpad-master/* .
>    sudo rmdir asus-wmi-screenpad-master
>    sudo rm master.zip
>    ```
>
>    Now the source code should be in `/usr/src/asus-wmi-1.0`. It's important that the folder is called exactly like that because DKMS expects that. Alternatively you can of course also clone this git repository into that folder.
> 4. If not using kernel 5.4: Call the following script to download and patch files fitting to your kernel version
>
>    ```
>    sudo sh prepare-for-current-kernel.sh
>    ```
> 5. Register the module with DKMS
>
>    ```
>    sudo dkms add -m asus-wmi -v 1.0
>    ```
> 6. Build and install the module to the current kernel
>
>    ```
>    sudo dkms build -m asus-wmi -v 1.0
>    sudo dkms install -m asus-wmi -v 1.0
>    ```
>
>    From now on, DKMS will automatically rebuild the module on every kernel update.
> 7. After rebooting, you should now find a new device in `/sys/class/leds/asus::screenpad`. To set the brightness of the screen, simply call
>
>    ```
>    echo XXX | sudo tee '/sys/class/leds/asus::screenpad/brightness'
>    ```
>
>    where `XXX` is a value between 0 and 255 (0 turns the screen completely off, 255 sets it to maximum brightness). To allow every user to set the brightness without using `sudo`, call
>
>    ```
>    sudo chmod a+w '/sys/class/leds/asus::screenpad/brightness'
>    ```
>
>    Now you can set the brightness by simply executing
>
>    ```
>    echo XXX > '/sys/class/leds/asus::screenpad/brightness'
>    ```
>
>    `chmod` has to be executed again after every reboot, so it is advisable to add the call to a boot script, e.g. `/etc/rc.local`.
> 8. You can now also use the functionality of your Desktop Environment to map the function keys on the keyboard to actions of your choice. For example, you can create a script that toggles the state of the screenpad and map it to the "Toggle ScreenPad" key.
>
> #### Removing or reinstalling
>
> If you want to re-download and reinstall the kernel module (maybe because there have been changes in the code), you have to remove the old one first, calling
>
> ```
> sudo dkms remove -m asus-wmi -v 1.0 --all
> sudo rm -r /usr/src/asus-wmi-1.0
> ```
>
> Then repeat the steps above from step 2 on.

There are also some other workarounds discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/s-light/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-Duo-UX581GV/issues/1).

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of [ddcutil](http://www.ddcutil.com)

Embedded laptop displays have a rudimentary I2C implementation. It's possible to read the EDID at slave address x50, but the DDC/CI protocol is not implemented on slave address x37. So ddcutil sees the displays (it can read the EDIDs) but DDC/CI communication fails.

Typically, such displays are controlled using ACPI.